# How can I.... SELECT *, lcase(name) AS name FROM table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to modify the name column and make it lowercase, but I also want to select all the other columns. Is there a way to do this without having to write the name of each column.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT *, lcase(name) AS name FROM table;
```

Instead of writing out all the column names, like this:

```
SELECT lcase(name) AS name, zip, address, age, birthday, etc FROM table;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but one option is to use a view:

```
create view table_with_lower_name as
select lcase(name) AS name, zip, address, age, birthday, etc 
from table;
```

Once defined (ie this is a one-time create statement), you can use simply:

```
select * from table_with_lower_name;
```

There are some caveats when using views, like you can't update modified columns (like `name` here) through them, but it might work for you.

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, there's no syntax like `SELECT (* EXCEPT name)...`, but I believe this answers the question best and while it is a workaround, it isn't hacky. The problem is if you want to do this with a lot of different queries, you'd have to create a view for each query, and that would most certainly be way more work than if you were to just flat out specify all of the column names right in the query (which is actually better practice anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works as it is! Though `select *` is considered bad form and can be a performance hit.

You may also prefer to use a table alias to make it clearer:

```
SELECT t.*, lcase(t.name) AS name FROM table t;
```

Comment: i think this answer is fine.. just give an another name for lcase like "lcase(t.name) AS lower_name" to avoid confusion to system.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no notation to select all columns except one apart from listing all the columns explicitly.

(Actually it is possible using dynamic SQL but you *really* don't want to do that.)